# How to write JPA IN query to check a collection has given set of values.?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Device extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    @ElementCollection
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<String> labels;
}
```

Now I need to check whether what are the devices existing for the given label set.

Below are the querirs that I tried.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT d FROM Device d JOIN d.labels l WHERE d.entity.id IN :entity_ids AND l IN :labels ")
List<Device> find(@Param("entity_ids") Set<Long> entityIds, @Param("labels") Set<String> labels);

@Query("SELECT d FROM Device d WHERE d.entity.id IN :entity_ids AND  d.labels IN :labels") List<Device> 
find(@Param("entity_ids") Set<Long> entityIds, @Param("labels") Set<String> labels);
```

This ended up with en error.

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter
> value [D2_label1] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection
> (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Parameter value [D2_label1] did not match expected type
> [java.util.Collection (n/a)]  at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:373)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do what you want. As it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-in-predicate):

> `IN` predicates performs a check that a particular value is in a list of values. Its syntax is:
>
> `in_expression` ::= `single_valued_expression` [NOT] IN `single_valued_list`
>
> `single_valued_list` ::= `constructor_expression` | (subquery) | `collection_valued_input_parameter`
>
> `constructor_expression` ::= (expression[, expression]*)
>
> The types of the `single_valued_expression` and the individual values in the `single_valued_list` must be consistent.
>
> JPQL limits the valid types here to string, numeric, date, time, timestamp, and enum types, and, in JPQL, single_valued_expression can only refer to:
>
> - "state fields", which is its term for simple attributes. Specifically, **this excludes association** and component/embedded attributes.
> - entity type expressions. See Entity type.
>
> In HQL, `single_valued_expression` can refer to a far more broad set of expression types. **Single-valued association are allowed**, and so are component/embedded attributes, although that feature depends on the level of support for tuple or "row value constructor syntax" in the underlying database.

So, I see the following approaches:

1. Rewrite your query in the following way:

```java
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT d FROM Device d join fetch d.labels WHERE d.entity.id IN :entity_ids")
List<Device> find(@Param("entity_ids") Set<Long> entityIds);
```

and then do further filtering in java code.

2. Rewrite your entity mapping for example in this way:

```java
@Entity
public class Device extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany
    private List<Label> labels;
}

@Entity
public class Label
{
   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String text;
}
```

and then use the following query:

```java
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT d FROM Device d join fetch d.labels l WHERE d.entity.id IN :entity_ids and l.text in :labels")
List<Device> find(@Param("entity_ids") Set<Long> entityIds, @Param("labels") Set<String> labels);
```

P.S. Please also note that `LazyCollectionOption.FALSE` is deprecated since you should use the JPA `FetchType` attribute of the `@ElementCollection`. See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-LazyCollection).

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view you should write the `IN` clause in brackets:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT d FROM Device d JOIN d.labels l WHERE d.entity.id IN (:entity_ids) AND l IN (:labels)")
List<Device> find(@Param("entity_ids") Set<Long> entityIds, @Param("labels") Set<String> labels);

@Query("SELECT d FROM Device d WHERE d.entity.id IN (:entity_ids) AND  d.labels IN (:labels)") List<Device> 
find(@Param("entity_ids") Set<Long> entityIds, @Param("labels") Set<String> labels);
```

Comment: Hi @Patrick thanks for your answer. But it is not working either. Ended up with below error.


org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)

Answer (score 0):

This is correct:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT d FROM Device d JOIN d.labels l WHERE d.entity.id IN :entity_ids AND l IN :labels ")
List<Device> find(@Param("entity_ids") Set<Long> entityIds, @Param("labels") Set<String> labels);
```

Can you share the error you are getting when using this query?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1
2021-02-12 16:55:38,379 INFO  [http-nio-8082-exec-3] UUID:6f6f7400-9716-43e4-8ffb-d4740825fc18 lk.adl.iot.sima.controller.GlobalExceptionController: Unexpected exception occurs : 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: Well, what is the SQL and the error that MySQL reports?